# How to fix 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined" and 'Unable to require Taiko"

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu, getgauge

Trying to run gauge with taiko to automate some web testing. `sudo gauge run specs` throws two type errors and "Unable to require Taiko"

Taiko, nodejs, npm are installed and working fine. Gauge seems mostly fine. `gauge init js` worked. 
I've tried moving the .spec file into different dirs, and moving taiko and nodejs around, with no difference.

To replicate, with everything necessary installed:

```
gauge init js

gauge run specs
```

Should run the .spec file created by 'init'

Actually output too long to include, but will show on request. 
Errors:

1)

```
Unable to require module 'taiko' in /home/harry/tests/step_implementation.js
Trace: Error: Cannot find module 'taiko'
Require stack:
- /home/harry/tests/step_implementation.js
```

2)

```
const { openBrowser,write, closeBrowser, goto, press, text, focus, inputField, toRightOf } = require('taiko');

^
TypeError: Cannot destructure property `openBrowser` of 'undefined' or 'null'.
```

3)

```
new Test(step.fn, parameters, timeout).run().then(

^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined
```

4)

```
[Gauge]
Connection to runner with Pid 15653 lost. The runner probably quit unexpectedly.
```

Comment: Please see the rules / https://stackoverflow.com/conduct... this question is NOT well formed.

Answer (score 0):

You should check your node_modules once. This kind of error happens when you don't have taiko in your node_modules.
When you do `gauge init js` it is added to your local node_modules. Something might have messed up so I guess Taiko is not in your node_modules try running
`npm install --save taiko`. This might solve your issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Whats the file, the context, the OS>.. the reason why is because the monikier is mangled...

undefined is a result of a charset mismatch of some syymbolc IMHO...

Answer (score 0):

Trace: Error: Cannot find module 'taiko' completely tells you that taiko is not installed , run `npm i taiko` and try again.